# Как в Newtonsoft.Json для объекта конвертации определить свойство как XML атрибут

Tags: json, xml, vb.net

Имеем `Newtonsoft.Json` библиотеку и два класса.

Класс 1:

```
Public Class SomeClass

    Private _some_property As String
    Public Property SomeProperty() As String
        Get
            Return _some_property
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _some_property = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Класс 2:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class SomeWrapper

    Private _items As IList(Of SomeClass) = New List(Of SomeClass)

    <JsonProperty("Wrapper")>
    Public Property Items() As IList(Of SomeClass)
        Get
            Return _items
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As IList(Of SomeClass))
            _items = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

И следующий клиентский код:

```
    Dim someObj As New SomeClass
    Dim someWrap As New SomeWrapper

    someObj.SomeProperty = "blablabla"

    someWrap.Items.Add(someObj)
    someWrap.Items.Add(someObj)
    someWrap.Items.Add(someObj)

    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someWrap, Formatting.Indented)
    Dim node As XNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "root")

    Dim result As String = node.ToString
```

В переменной `json` имеем:

```
{
  "Wrapper": [
    {
      "SomeProperty": "blablabla"
    },
    {
      "SomeProperty": "blablabla"
    },
    {
      "SomeProperty": "blablabla"
    }
  ]
}
```

В переменной `result` имеем:

```
<root>
  <Wrapper>
    <SomeProperty>blablabla</SomeProperty>
  </Wrapper>
  <Wrapper>
    <SomeProperty>blablabla</SomeProperty>
  </Wrapper>
  <Wrapper>
    <SomeProperty>blablabla</SomeProperty>
  </Wrapper>
</root>
```

Вопрос, как обозначить свойства объекта чтобы они в JSON были определены как XML атрибуты. То есть `SomeProperty` должны стать XML атрибутами а не узлами.

Comment: для примера выхода стоит еще и пример входа добавить

Comment: @Grundy привел подробный пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание: в строке `JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "root")` ваш класс не участвует никаким боком, идет прямое преобразование строки в XNode.

Поэтому ответ - никак. По крайней мере, без изменения формата JSON.

---

Если у вас возник вопрос - как нужно изменить формат JSON, чтобы SomeProperty стало атрибутом - попробуйте сделать обратное действие. Соберите нужный вам XML и попытайтесь преобразовать его в JSON.

Скорее всего, поможет атрибут `<JsonProperty("@SomeProperty")>`

Если же вам вообще не нужен JSON - забудьте про Newtonsoft.Json и воспользуйтесь `XmlSerializer`:

```
var serizliaer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeWrapper));
var doc = new XDocument();
using (var writer = doc.CreateWriter())
  serializer.Serialize(someWrap, writer);
var node = doc.Root;
node.Remove();
```

Comment: Большая просьба не переливать из пустого в порожнее. Не надо ни от чего отказываться и не надо менять технологии. Вопрос и заключается в том как используя именно эту библиотеку получить из объектов вышеописанных именно `XML` и так чтобы `SomeProperty` стал атрибутом. В вашем примере нет достигнутого результата.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь цитирую: *"Поэтому ответ - никак."*

Comment: В библиотеке `Newtonsoft.Json` имеется возможность изменять `JSON`  но собственно примера я какраз найти в документации и не смог, маловато знаний английского

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь так у вас формат JSON задан - или меняется? Если задан - то никак. Если меняется - я ответил что можно сделать.

Comment: Например объявить тип для объекта я знаю как, а вот как атрибуты задать незнаю.

Comment: для того чтобы `SomeProperty` стал атрибутом, надо чтобы в JSON у него было название не 'SomeProperty' а '@SomeProperty'

Comment: какой формат JSON должен быть известно, неизвестно как его получить из вышеописанных объектов.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь если знаете это - так и надо было спрашивать

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45834/discussion-between---and-pavel-mayorov).